# Ember CLI, locationType: ‘hash’, and serving index.html for all URLs

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have a particular use case where I want to use the URL hash for routing within Ember, AND I want for the path part of the URL to be somewhat dynamic too.

For example:

```
localhost:4200/#/properties/edit
```

Would work exactly the same as this:

```
localhost:4200/about/#/properties/edit
```

Or this:

```
localhost:4200/products/widgets/model-5000/#/properties/edit
```

It would be 100% acceptable if navigating between these different example URLs above would produce a full page refresh, though any hash change in the URL would keep it on the "single page."

I want for all of these URLs to point to the `app/index.html` file and for Ember CLI to kind of "ignore" the path, but I cannot figure out how to configure Ember CLI to do this when it's serving the app. For example, the `/about` scenario above gives me the error `Cannot GET /about`.

Is this possible with plain vanilla Ember CLI, or will I need to turn to something like `ember-cli-rails` to have more flexible routing in development? I'd assume that configuring this to work properly in production would be relatively simple, but I need something that works for development too.

Comment: Possible solution is to create an addon with "server middleware" that behaves similarly to what the native HistorySupportAddon does. https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/blob/master/lib/tasks/server/middleware/history-support/index.js#L13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create an Ember CLI add-on: [ember-cli-hash-anywhere](https://github.com/liveeditor/ember-cli-hash-anywhere).

With that installed, the web server ignores the path part of the URL and serves up `index.html` every time.

Comment: Seems like you should be able to make your own 'location'.

Comment: Yep, found it! https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.10.0/packages/ember-routing/lib/location/api.js#L151-L178

Comment: It's an interesting idea, but I think my add-on is more practical for my purposes. I want everything that "hash" offers but just need for the development server to behave a little differently. In production, configuring Nginx or Apache to do what I need should be trivial. I was just fighting Ember CLI's server for development in this case.

Comment: It's deprecated now this module :/
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-hash-anywhere

Comment: @mEnE, right, I wrote that package and then deprecated it. It's no longer needed as of ~4 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use a wildcard: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_wildcard-globbing-routes

import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('index', { path: "/*wildcard" }, function() {
    this.route("properties", function() {
      this.route("edit");
    });
  });
});

export default Router;
```

Comment: I wish this would have worked. I believe the `path` you list above as a wildcard is the path _after_ the hash, not before it. So unfortunately, this does not solve my problem. I still get the error `Cannot GET /about`.

Comment: Read the hash location docs, and you're right. With the location: hash set, everything after the hash is the url the router uses.

Comment: I appreciate your willingness to help. A million thanks!